# how to store the location of a detected face opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I can get the values with `for (x, y, w, h) in faces:` as long as there is a face detected, but after no faces are detected I lose those values.

I want to draw a rectangle to cover the area where the last face was detected and stays there for a certain time, but rectangle dissapears at the moment when face is not detected.

I tried to pass the values to new variables with `copy.copy()` but the rectangle keeps dissapearing.

```
faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.3, minNeighbors=3, minSize=(0, 0))

for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
    if x>0: x2 = copy.copy(x)
    if y>0: y2 = copy.copy(y)
    if w>0: w2 = copy.copy(w)
    if h>0: h2 = copy.copy(h)
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x2, y2), (x2+w2, y2+h2), (0, 0, 0), -1)
```

Edit:
For those who want more context, I basically want to track hand movements, Im doing color segmentation to detect skin and the face is interfering with the tracking since sometimes the haar detector doesnt detect the face affecting the hand position estimation, the first aproach I took was removing the face, I know there are better methods but Im new to OpenCV.

I made it storing the values in a list,

```
faces_t = [None]*4

while(cam.isOpened():

faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(grey, scaleFactor=1.3, minNeighbors=3, minSize=(0, 0))

for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
   faces_t.pop(0)
   faces_t.insert(0,x)
   faces_t.pop(1)
   faces_t.insert(1,y)
   faces_t.pop(2)
   faces_t.insert(2,w)
   faces_t.pop(3)
   faces_t.insert(3,w)

X1 = faces_t[0]
Y1 = faces_t[1]
W1 = faces_t[2]
H1 = faces_t[3]

if any(value is None for value in faces_t):
    pass
else:
    cv2.rectangle(skin_ycrcb, (X1-10, Y1-15), (X1+W1+10, Y1+H1+15), (0, 0, 0), -1)
```

Comment: I really dont think there is enough code here for context, can you provide part of the bigger class?

Comment: you copy to the same variables in a for loop... at the end you will have the last one that passed the if... not sure why you copy integers using copy.copy... Also, you should only do 1 if with all the conditions, or you may get part of one and part of another if one has 0 in a component

Answer (score 0):

You can just use this:

```
faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.3, 
minNeighbors=3, minSize=(0, 0))
(X1,Y1,W1,H1) = (0,0,0,0)
for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
    if (x,y,w,h) != (0,0,0,0):
       (X1,Y1,W1,H1) = (x,y,w,h)
    cv2.rectangle(img, (X1, Y1), (X1+W1, Y1+H1), (0, 0, 0), -1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it didn't work, I think is because the values are integers, and therefore immutable, `(X1,Y1,W1,H1) = (x,y,w,h)` won't work